# Why Oracle ascii function return >255 code?

Tags: oracle, select, ascii

When using Oracle ascii function:

```
select ascii('A') from dual;
```

It return 65 is right.

But,when i using:

```
select ascii('周') from dual;
```

The return is 55004.The ascii can represent>255???

How to explain?

Help!!!!

My oracle version:Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
my Characterset:6   NLS_CHARACTERSET    ZHS16GBK

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions014.htm

Answer (score 4):

`ASCII` in the name is a holdover from when Oracle only supported ASCII.  It does not mean it only returns ASCII values.

From the docs:

> ASCII returns the decimal representation in the database character set of the first character of char.
>
> http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions013.htm#sthref933

So the result depends on the database character set, which can be greater than 255.

Comment: +1. Next question: what does Oracle think the term "decimal representation" means? :-P

Comment: @ruakh lol :)  I guess they used "decimal" as a synonym for "numeric". Mind you, it does return a `NUMBER`, which in Oracle is internally stored in a decimal format, kind of...

Comment: @ruakh - I know you're kidding, but I assume they meant decimal as base-10, as opposed to the hexadecimal or octal representation/notation (rather than the [mathematic meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_representation)).

Comment: @AlexPoole: But it's returning a number (`NUMBER`), not a string (`VARCHAR` or whatnot), so it's not *in* a notation. It doesn't *have* a base.

Comment: @ruakh - right, though it's implicitly base 10; but I think the docs are just explicitly saying that. It's the only hint that the return type is a number. If you did `ascii(<variable>)` and got back `38`, you need to know it's decimal to know it's `&` rather than `8`, say. I agree it would have to be a string to hold a hex value, but for some characters it might not be obvious at first glance. Mostly I think it's just that ASCII (etc.) values are often shown in hex, so it's removing ambiguity about what you're going to get - it's saying you'll get the decimal number, not a hex or octal string?

Comment: @AlexPoole: It's not "implicitly base 10". It's just a number. If you're a human writing `ascii(<variable>)` and getting back `38`, you know it's `&` because you can also see what `<variable>` is. If you're a program getting back `38`, you know it's `&` because you're not getting back the string `'38'`, you're getting a number in an unambiguous internal representation. (Decimal `38` and hex `26` and octal `46` are all the same.)

Comment: @ruakh - I think we're talking at cross purposes a bit, and this probably isn't the place. (I'll certainly concede your 'internal representation' point, and the rest is semantics *8-). What I meant was that if you're testing something like `if ascii(var) = 38 then ...` then you need to know what will match 38. (Contrived, I know). Anyway, I think that's what the docs are saying, that you get a number not a string, because a hex value is common when talking ASCII.

Comment: @AlexPoole, ruakh is definitely right on this one.  Numbers only have a base when they're converted to strings.  Remember internally everything is stored in base 2, but we almost never show them in strings as base 2.

Answer (score 1):

This may vary with your version of Oracle, but it is probably trying to do you the favor of gracefully handling the non-7bit ASCII value that you are passing (but should not be). The doc in at least one version discusses some handling of non-ASCII inputs (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions007.htm) though if you are using a different version of oracle you may want to refer to the appropriate docs.

If your docs don't say anything more about how it handles non-7bit characters then the answer is probably not well defined (ie no guarantee from Oracle on behavior) and you may want to consider cleansing your input so you only try calling the ASCII function on values that you know to be in the proper input set.